# Validate Historic Date in dd/mm/yy php

Tags: php, validation, date

I have a text input where the user enters the date in dd/mm/yy format.  On submit, it checks both whether or not the date is valid, and also that the date is in the past (which it needs to be).  I am using the below code, however whilst thi sworks great on my development area, the server that it's hosted on only has PHP version 5.2.17 and I think what I've got only works on 5.3 or above.  Is there a solution to convert the entry to dd/mm/yy and make sure it's historical?  Thankyou!

```
if (isset($_POST['SubmitSave'])) {  
//date validation  


if($_POST['DateOfCall']!=NULL)  
{  
    $dt = $_POST['DateOfCall'];  
    $array = explode("/",$dt);  

    $day = $array[0];  
    $month = $array[1];  
    $year = $array[2];  

    if(!checkdate( $month,$day, $year))  
    {  
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   ,   'alert ( "Not a Valid Date of Call" );'
   , '</script>';
    }  
    else  
    {  


    $today = time();
    $Date_Entry =$_POST['DateOfCall']; 

$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $Date_Entry)->format('d/m/Y');

    $dt = strtotime($show_date);


    if($dt > $today){ 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   ,   'alert ( "Date of Call is in the future..." );'
   , '</script>';
    }



    unset($dt);
    unset($Date_Entry); 


    }  
}  



}


else if......
```

Comment: What happens when run on 5.2?

Comment: It just sort of drops out, the validation chunk at the top works fine, but not  DateTime:;CreatefromFormat section.  The Alert doesn't comeup and the page doesn't reload, you have to use the back button to get back to the form.

Comment: I appreciate that sometimes we don't have a choice about which version we use, but if at all possible I strongly recommend upgrading your php version -- be aware that PHP 5.2 has been unsupported for several years now and has known sercurity issues that will not be patched. If you run out-of-date software on your production servers, you are in danger of being hacked. Even php 5.3 is nearing official end-of-life now that 5.5 has been released. If you're still stuck on 5.2, it is *way* past time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php
    //$date = "18/12/2013"; # bad
    $date = "18/1/2013"; # good
    list($day, $month, $year) = explode("/", $date);
    if (checkdate($month, $day, $year) && strtotime("$year/$month/$day") < time()) {
        echo "good";
    } else {
        echo "bad";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following code:

```
$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $Date_Entry)->format('d/m/Y');
$dt = strtotime($show_date);
```

Your problem is that `createFromFormat()` was only added in PHP 5.3, so it won't work in 5.2.

Given that, your question boild down to basically being just a duplicate of [php dateTime::createFromFormat in 5.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399075/php-datetimecreatefromformat-in-5-2)

To summarise the answer given there, php 5.2 and earlier doesn't really have any good solutions for importing dates; it has several bad solutions, of which `strtotime()` is the most obvious. You could try

```
$dt = strtotime($Date_Entry);
```

That *should* be enough to do what you want. But just be careful of the known quirks with `strtotime()` and ambiguous date formats (like `m/d/y`).

In php 5.3 and above, you should use `createFromFormat()` instead of `strtotime()`.

Hope that helps.

As an aside, it's worth noting that even in 5.3, the code you've written (that I quoted at the top of this answer) is redundant; there is no need to use `strtotime()` here, because the `DateTime::format()` method can output the timestamp directly. You simply need this:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $Date_Entry)->format('U');
```